# visual studio code associated file types are unrecognizable

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code (VSC) on Windows 10. I've changed a couple of file types to be associated with VSC. Just out of sheer convenience, really. Before that, some of my file types had generic or ugly icons. I figured out VSC would replace them with appropriate ones. It seems I was wrong. Now all of the associated file types look unrecognizable. Actually, they look the same, which is the opposite of what I wanted to achieve after all. Is VSC missing this spot or is it me doing something wrong?

Would anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The icons for each filetype are stored in the Registry using *indirection*. By associating other filetypes with VSC, you've adopted that icon for all.

You can edit the Registry (with care!) to substitute another icon for each filetype. If you've installed 7-Zip, examine `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.*`, where the asterisk denotes all its supported archive formats, such as .arj or .zip, to see how differing icons are provided for each format.

For example, looking up `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip` in the Registry, I find the (Default) filetype is `7-Zip.zip`, because 7-Zip has been installed and set as the default. Scrolling to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.zip`, the `(Default)` value for key `Defaulticon` is `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll,1`. If the path were changed to `%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-1001`, Zip files would show the icon used for MS Libraries:

[image: MS Lie Berry icon]